# Outlined text with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to know if there is a way to draw "outlined text" with ggplot2, for example black text with a small white border, in order to make it easily readable on backgrounds such as maps.

Ideally I'd like to achieve the same type of labels you can see on Google Maps :

[image]

Thanks in advance for any hints !

Comment: [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734535/control-font-thickness-without-changing-font-size)

Comment: There is now a pkg for this: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shadowtext/vignettes/shadowtext.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is an approach that implements the general idea from the `shadowtext` function in the `TeachingDemos` package.  The code for the middle part could be wrapped into a function to simplify some things.  The example is blatantly stolen from Richie Cotton's answer:

```
d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 10), ]  


p <- ggplot(d, aes(carat, price) ) 
theta <- seq(pi/8, 2*pi, length.out=16)
xo <- diff(range(d$carat))/200
yo <- diff(range(d$price))/200
for(i in theta) {
    p <- p + geom_text( 
        bquote(aes(x=carat+.(cos(i)*xo),y=price+.(sin(i)*yo),label=cut)), 
                    size=12, colour='black' )
}
p <- p + geom_text( aes(label=cut), size=12, colour='white' )
p <- p + opts( panel.background=theme_rect(fill='green' ) )
print(p)
```

[image]

Comment: adding many new layers is probably a bit overkill, you could instead define a [grob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734535/control-font-thickness-without-changing-font-size)+geom that replaces `textGrob+geom_text` as one layer.

Comment: That is very cunning.  I like it.

Comment: Another small problem is that all the black labels are written at once, and then all the white labels. That's not ideal where labels overlap such as in the bottom left corner of your example. But that's certainly the best answer so far, thanks !

Comment: @baptiste, that is a good idea, do you have any references or pointers on how to define a grob+geom object?

Comment: @GregSnow there's no real reference apart from the source code. The only guide [that I know of](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Creating-a-new-geom) is a bit outdated and unclear. The easiest thing would be to copy the code of `geom-text.r`, give it a new name, replace the `textGrob` used in its draw method with a vectorised version of `gridExtra::stextGrob`.

Comment: Very nice solution! If you add `alpha` you get a nice shade gradient; e.g. `bquote(aes(x=carat+.(cos(i)*xo),y=price+.(sin(i)*yo),label=cut)), size=12, colour='black', alpha=1/8)`

Answer (score 29):

Much simplier solution is to use `shadowtext` library and use `geom_shadowtext` instead of `geom_text`

Comment: Is there any way to combine `geom_shadowtext` with `geom_text_repel`?

Comment: EDIT: my previous question has been also asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56318012/using-ggrepel-and-shadowtext-on-the-same-geom-text

Answer (score 6):

Not ideal or very flexible but you can get the effect by drawing bold mono text, then standard mono text on top.

I've used a green panel background to simulate the map.

```
d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 10), ]

(p <- ggplot(d, aes(carat, price)) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = cut, family = "mono", fontface = "bold"), 
    size = 12, 
    colour = "black"
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = cut, family = "mono"), 
    size = 12, 
    colour = "white"
  ) +
  opts(panel.background = theme_rect(fill = "green"))
)
```

[image: text-on-bold-text with the diamonds dataset]

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer by Greg Snow doesn't work anymore with `ggplot2@2.2.1` because of the call of `aes` instead of `aes_q`.

Use

```
for(i in theta) {
  p <- p + geom_text( 
    aes_q(x = bquote(carat+.(cos(i)*xo)),
          y = bquote(price+.(sin(i)*yo)),
          label = ~cut), 
    size=12, colour='black' )
}
```

instead.