# Plotting points from a data.frame using OpenStreetMap

Tags: r, openstreetmap, ggmap

I am a complete novice with spacial data. I have the following code that successfully plots a bounded map. I would like to add, as points the data.frame stores.
I apologize in advance for not being able to figure this out from the OpenStreetMap documentation...code below:

```
library(OpenStreetMap)
stores <- data.frame(name=c("Commercial","Union","Bedford"),
                 longitude=c(-70.25042295455933,-70.26050806045532,-70.27726650238037),
                 latitude=c(43.657471302616806,43.65663299041943,43.66091757424481))
lat <- c(43.68093,43.64278)
lon <- c(-70.29548,-70.24097)
portland <- openmap(c(lat[1],lon[1]),c(lat[2],lon[2]),zoom=15,'osm')
plot(portland,raster=TRUE)
#can't figure out what to put here.
```

I suspect the format of stores isn't proper for spatial data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know the `OpenStreetMap` package. But I offer an alternative that still draws an OpenStreet Map, but uses the `ggmap` package to fetch and draw the map. The `get_map` function can fetch maps from a variety of sources: osm, google, stamen, and cloudmade; set with `source`. In addition the sources have different styles, set with `maptype`.  The boundary of the map is given in a location vector. Alternatively, the location vector can give the centre of the map with an appropriate zoom level set. The map is drawn with `ggplot2`, and so points and labels can be added to the map as if they were being added to any ggplot object. To run the following, the `ggmap` and `ggplot2` packages need to be installed.

```
library(ggmap)

stores <- data.frame(name=c("Commercial","Union","Bedford"),
        longitude=c(-70.25042295455933,-70.26050806045532,-70.27726650238037),
        latitude=c(43.657471302616806,43.65663299041943,43.66091757424481))
location = c(-70.2954, 43.64278, -70.2350, 43.68093)

# Fetch the map
portland = get_map(location = location, source = "osm")

# Draw the map
portlandMap = ggmap(portland)

# Add the points layer
portlandMap = portlandMap + geom_point(data = stores, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), size = 5)

# Add the labels
portlandMap + geom_text(data = stores, aes(label = name, x = longitude+.001, y = latitude), hjust = 0)
```

The result is:

[image]

The labels could be getting lost in the background. In that case, something like this might be appropriate. It uses [code from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686054/outlined-text-with-ggplot2) to give the text an outline.

```
portlandMap = ggmap(portland) + geom_point(data = stores, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), size = 5)

theta <- seq(pi/16, 2*pi, length.out=32)
xo <- diff(location[c(1,3)])/250
yo <- diff(location[c(2,4)])/250

for(i in theta) {
    portlandMap <- portlandMap + geom_text(data = stores,  
    aes_(x = stores$longitude + .001 + cos(i) * xo, 
         y = stores$latitude + sin(i) * yo, 
         label = stores$name), 
    size = 5, colour = 'black', hjust = 0)
 }

portlandMap + 
   geom_text(data = stores, aes(x = longitude + .001, y = latitude, label=name), 
     size = 5, colour = 'white', hjust = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: There is an error when using ```get_map``` in 2022. ```Error: 'get_openstreetmap' is defunct```
See https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/117

Answer (score 4):

Since google startend requiring billing information for using their api, here is a solution using OpenStreetMaps only.

**sample data**

```
library( OpenStreetMap )
library( ggplot2 )
stores <- data.frame(name=c("Commercial","Union","Bedford"),
                     longitude=c(-70.25042295455933,-70.26050806045532,-70.27726650238037),
                     latitude=c(43.657471302616806,43.65663299041943,43.66091757424481))
lat <- c(43.68093,43.64278)
lon <- c(-70.29548,-70.24097)

portland <- OpenStreetMap::openmap( c( lat[1], lon[1] ), c( lat[2], lon[2] ),zoom = 15, 'osm')
```

the OSM-map is in mercator, and the store-coordinates are lat-lon, so:
method 1: convert the map to latlon
method 2: convert or the coordinates to mercator

**method 1 - convert map to latlon**

```
autoplot( OpenStreetMap::openproj( portland ) ) +
  geom_point( data = stores, aes( x = longitude, y = latitude, size = 5 ) ) +
  geom_text( data = stores, aes( x = longitude + .001, y = latitude, label = name ), hjust = 0 ) +
  theme( legend.position = "none" )
```

[image]

**method 2 - convert points to mercator**

```
stores2 <- as.data.frame( 
  OpenStreetMap::projectMercator( lat = stores$latitude, 
                                  long = stores$longitude ) 
  )
stores2 <- cbind( stores, stores2)
autoplot( portland ) +
  geom_point( data = stores2, aes( x = x, y = y, size = 5 ) ) +
  geom_text( data = stores2, aes( x = x + 100, y = y, label = name ), hjust = 0 ) +
  theme( legend.position = "none" )
```

[image]