# Text labels with outline in R

Tags: r, text, plot

I wonder whether it is possible to draw text with an outline in R, such that the text is readable independent of the background (like the text on memes). The following (obviously) fails:

```
# prepare a colorful background
randcolors <- sprintf( "#%02X%02X%02X99", sample(1:255, 1000, replace=T), sample(1:255, 1000,replace=T), sample(1:255, 1000, replace=T))
plot( NULL, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1), xaxt="n", bty="n", yaxt="n")
points( runif(1000, 0, 1 ), runif( 1000, 0, 1 ), cex=runif(1000, 0.5, 5), col= randcolors, pch= 19)
text( 0.5, 0.5, "test text", cex= 5 )
text( 0.5, 0.5, "test text", cex= 4.5, col="white" )
```

The result is not spectacular:

[image]

Clearly, I can first create a white or semi-transparent background, but I would actually much prefer to have nice outlines.

Comment: this link may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734535/control-font-thickness-without-changing-font-size

Comment: Some possibilities for `ggplot` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686054/outlined-text-with-ggplot2/10691826#10691826).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `shadowtext` from the `TeachingDemos` package:

```
 shadowtext( 0.5, 0.5, "test text", cex= 4.5, col="white" , r=0.3)
```

[image: shadow text]

Comment: The `shadowtext` function is interesting because it's basically the OP's intuition, [just repeated a bunch of times](https://github.com/cran/TeachingDemos/blob/master/R/shadowtext.R).

Comment: Not really, the OP is scaling the text size, but shadowtext uses multiple copies at the same size as the main text. Scaling doesn't work to create shadows on internal holes.

Comment: Is there any similar function that can be used in `ggplot2`?

Comment: @Ilya see Henrik's link in the comment on the question.