# How to combine repelling labels and shadow or halo text in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

There are some nice solutions for either repelling labels in ggplot2 (e.g. [ggrepel](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html)) or shadow text for labels (e.g. [ggshadowtext](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shadowtext/vignettes/shadowtext.html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25631216/1036500)). But nothing that allows us to combine these two functions.

I tried this hack that prints the labels many times in slightly different locations, but it doesn't go well with `geom_text_repel`

```
library(ggplot2)

# subset data
d <- diamonds[1:20,]

# make plot
p <- ggplot(d, aes(carat, price)) +
  geom_point()

# make halo layers
theta <- seq(pi / 8, 2 * pi, length.out = 16)
xo <- diff(range(d$carat)) / 200
yo <- diff(range(d$price)) / 200
for (i in theta) {
  p <- p + 
    geom_text_repel(data = d, 
              aes_q(x = bquote(carat + .(cos(i) * xo)),
                    y = bquote(price + .(sin(i) * yo)),
                    label = ~cut),
              size = 6,
              colour = 'black', 
              seed = 1,
              segment.colour = NA)
}

# update plot with halo and interior text
p <- p + geom_text_repel(aes(label = cut),
                   size = 6,
                   colour = 'white', 
                   seed = 1,
                   segment.colour = "grey80")

p
```

It is very slow, and in the locations where the labels are close, this method is not effective:

[image]

How can we get shadow text that works with `geom_text_repel`? I [posted an issue](https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel/issues/103) about this to the ggrepel GitHub repo some time ago, but there has been no reply (perhaps it's impossible?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This feature has now been [added](https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel/commit/9ec17e3491145e89dab4f696bf9ade57d4be7a88) to the ggrepel package, and it is awesome!

```
library(ggrepel)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- mtcars
dat$car <- rownames(dat)

ggplot(dat) +
  aes(wt, 
      mpg, 
      label = car) +
  geom_point(colour = "red") +
  geom_text_repel(bg.color = "white",
                  bg.r = 0.25)
```

[image]