# Outlined letters in text ggplot2 - 538 style

Tags: r, ggplot2

Does anyone know whether it’s possible to replicate in ggplot2 538’s feature of outlining text in a plot?

In the example attached. Would it be possible to add the rounded white outline to the percentage?

[image]

Comment: Related post: [How to combine repelling labels and shadow or halo text in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56798482/how-to-combine-repelling-labels-and-shadow-or-halo-text-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be the [shadowtext](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shadowtext/vignettes/shadowtext.html#ggplot2-layer-geom_shadowtext) package and a second one would be `ggrepel`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(shadowtext)

df <- data.frame(
  x = factor(1),
  y = factor(1),
  label = "78%"
)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, label = label)) +
  geom_tile(fill = "firebrick") +
  geom_shadowtext(color = "black", size = 14 / .pt, fontface = "bold", bg.colour = "white", bg.r = .2) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

```r
library(ggrepel)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, label = label)) +
  geom_tile(fill = "firebrick") +
  geom_text_repel(color = "black", size = 14 / .pt, fontface = "bold", bg.colour = "white", bg.r = .2, force = 0) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't know either shadowtext or this particular ggrepel feature. Neat. Learning point of the day :)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `sprintf` to add an underline under the label.
I've used `Arthritis` datset from `vcd` package to demonstrate this example.

Here's how you'll do it:

```
parseLabel <- sprintf("underline(%s)~\n~%s",
                      gsub(" ", "~", df$Treatment, fixed = TRUE),
                      gsub(" ", "~", length(df$Treatment), fixed = TRUE))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Treatment)) +
  geom_histogram(stat = "count") +
  stat_count(geom = "text", color = "white", size = 3.5,
             aes(label = parseLabel), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), parse = T)

p + theme_fivethirtyeight()
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Vishal but I’m not looking to underline the text. The goal is to add that white ‘bubble’ around it.

Comment: @PabloAB your question originally did say underline; I just changed it to outline, but this answer seems to be based on the terminology you used

Comment: Thank you Camille!