# Text color based on contrast against background

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, colors, label

I have the following plot:

```
m <- structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("FE", "AG", 
"NO", "SPH", "SEP", "H/I", "CMP"), class = "factor"), Var2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L
), .Label = c("FE", "AG", "NO", "SPH", "SEP", "H/I", "CMP"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(0, 0.0419753086419753, 0.172839506172839, 0.0740740740740741, 
    0.0123456790123457, 0.111111111111111, 0.0617283950617284, 
    0.0419753086419753, 0, 0.0765432098765432, 0.0246913580246914, 
    0.00493827160493827, 0.0567901234567901, 0.0320987654320988, 
    0.172839506172839, 0.0765432098765432, 0, 0.175308641975309, 
    0.0197530864197531, 0.177777777777778, 0.120987654320988, 
    0.0740740740740741, 0.0246913580246914, 0.175308641975309, 
    0, 0.00740740740740741, 0.0814814814814815, 0.0395061728395062, 
    0.0123456790123457, 0.00493827160493827, 0.0197530864197531, 
    0.00740740740740741, 0, 0.0197530864197531, 0.00987654320987654, 
    0.111111111111111, 0.0567901234567901, 0.177777777777778, 
    0.0814814814814815, 0.0197530864197531, 0, 0.0716049382716049, 
    0.0617283950617284, 0.0320987654320988, 0.120987654320988, 
    0.0395061728395062, 0.00987654320987654, 0.0716049382716049, 
    0), vtext = c("0.0%", "4.2%", "17.3%", "7.4%", "1.2%", "11.1%", 
    "6.2%", "4.2%", "0.0%", "7.7%", "2.5%", "0.5%", "5.7%", "3.2%", 
    "17.3%", "7.7%", "0.0%", "17.5%", "2.0%", "17.8%", "12.1%", 
    "7.4%", "2.5%", "17.5%", "0.0%", "0.7%", "8.1%", "4.0%", 
    "1.2%", "0.5%", "2.0%", "0.7%", "0.0%", "2.0%", "1.0%", "11.1%", 
    "5.7%", "17.8%", "8.1%", "2.0%", "0.0%", "7.2%", "6.2%", 
    "3.2%", "12.1%", "4.0%", "1.0%", "7.2%", "0.0%")), .Names = c("Var1", 
"Var2", "value", "vtext"), row.names = c(NA, -49L), class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = m, aes(x = Var2, y = Var1, fill = value, label = vtext)) +
    xlab("") + ylab("") +
    geom_tile() +
    geom_text() +
    scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="darkmagenta") +
    # Sample code for subtitles: ggtitle(bquote(atop("Age distribution", atop(italic(.(subtitle)), ""))))
    ggtitle(bquote(atop(.(title), atop(italic(.(subtitle)), "")))) +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
          axis.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"),
          plot.title = element_text(size = 20),
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
          legend.key.size = unit(0.02, "npc"),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 14),
          legend.title = element_text(size = 16))
```

Which results in:

[image]

The problem, is that the text in the darker squares is difficult to read. Is it possible to change the text color based on the background color, so the text in the clear boxes is black and in the darker boxes is white?

Comment: See also `geom_label`

Comment: an alternative would be to outline the text; it's a [bit clumsy at R level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734535/control-font-thickness-without-changing-font-size/7735339#7735339), but on devices like gridSVG it might be possible to do it more elegantly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add these two code lines:

```
geom_text(aes(color = value > 0.1)) +
scale_color_manual(guide = FALSE, values = c("black", "white"))
```

Here text color depends on value (`value > 0.1`) and colors are specified with `scale_color_manual`.

For the output like this:

[image]