# Contrast between label and background: determine if color is light or dark

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, colors, label

I have a barplot with labels in white. Sometimes the color of background is too light and the white label becomes illegible. I'm looking for a function that takes a color value and returns whether the color is dark or light. Then I can set the label color to white or black accordingly to obtain the best contrast against the background.

Comment: I'd prefer the black and white ... if I use grey then when the palette is gray the label will be again illegible.

Comment: Something like this maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281365/ggplot2-text-color-based-on-background-contrast. When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Also this function for calculating perceived brightness might help. https://trendct.org/2016/01/22/how-to-choose-a-label-color-to-contrast-with-background/. Don't know of any built-in implementation of it in R but it's clearly not too difficult to write into your own function.

Comment: @MrFlick thank you for the comments. The solution in your first comment is specific to that problem. I will then make a function based on your second comment. I just dont like reinventing the wheel if there exist such a thing already.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a strategy to implement picking a text color of black vs white based on the intensity scale in the (second) link provided by @MrFlick.

The blog cited a W3C publication: [a standard formula for calculating the perceived brightness of a color](https://www.w3.org/TR/AERT#color-contrast) that used an algorithm for RGB encoded colors:

```
 ((Red value X 299) + (Green value X 587) + (Blue value X 114)) / 1000
```

The `col2rgb` function delivers a 3-row matrix which I multiply by the factors offered in that webpage. I used an example of "red" as a background color and the chosen text would then be "white"

```
 c( "black", "white")[  1+(sum( col2rgb("red") *c(299, 587,114))/1000 < 123) ]
[1] "white"
```

Implemented as a function:

```
isDark <- function(colr) { (sum( col2rgb(colr) * c(299, 587,114))/1000 < 123) }
isDark("red")
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Just in case: in the function `col2rgb("red")` should be `col2rgb(colr)`

Comment: Thanks. Obvious when examined. Not so obvious when in a hurry.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `farver::decode_colour` to calculate luminance directly. This is the approach used by `scales::show_col`.

```
cols <- viridis::viridis(12)
hcl <- farver::decode_colour(cols, to = "hcl")
ifelse(hcl[, "l"] > 50, "black", "white") # cutoff between 0 and 100
```