# Change font color of one stacked bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

[image]

How do I change the font color for only the top stacked bar?

Comment: If your question is about changing color of the labels depending on color of the background in order to increase contrast, see e.g. [Contrast between label and background: determine if color is light or dark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49437263/contrast-between-label-and-background-determine-if-color-is-light-or-dark) and several "Linked" posts therein. For future questions, please consider to include some tiny toy data  and code for people to try out their solutions on.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP, try to provide a full representative example in the future.  Regardless, here's your plot pretty much replicated:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  value=c(12, 17, 14, 46, 41, 66, 14, 14, 14, 27, 28, 7),
  category=rep(LETTERS[1:4], each=3),
  gender=rep(c("Male", "Female", "Other"), 4)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x=gender, y=value)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill=category), position=position_stack(vjust=0.5, reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label=paste(value,"%")), size=5,
    position=position_stack(vjust=0.5)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d()
```

[image]

To apply the different color based on a criteria, you can just specify that criteria directly to the `color=` aesthetic in `geom_text()`.  Here, I'm just going to use an `ifelse()` function to define when to change the color.  This works, but doing it this way means that we're calculating on the fly, rather than *mapping* the result to our original data.  Since the color is selected in a way that is **not** tied to a column in our data, *you need to define this color outside of the `aes()` function.*  As such, the `geom_text()` function is modified accordingly:

```
geom_text(
    aes(label=paste(value,"%")), size=5,
    color=ifelse(df$category=="A", 'white', 'black'),
    position=position_stack(vjust=0.5))
```

[image]

Once again note - I define `color=` outside of `aes()`.  The other way to do this would be to map the color of text to `category`, then define the colors manually with `scale_color_manual()`.  It's actually more straightforward here to just use `ifelse()` outside `aes()`.  (plus, `position_stack()` is very wonky when working with text geoms...).

Answer (score -1):

You need to choose one function from the `scale_fill_`, here is a list

```
 [1] "scale_fill_binned"     "scale_fill_brewer"     "scale_fill_continuous"
 [4] "scale_fill_date"       "scale_fill_datetime"   "scale_fill_discrete"  
 [7] "scale_fill_distiller"  "scale_fill_fermenter"  "scale_fill_gradient"  
[10] "scale_fill_gradient2"  "scale_fill_gradientn"  "scale_fill_grey"      
[13] "scale_fill_hue"        "scale_fill_identity"   "scale_fill_manual"    
[16] "scale_fill_ordinal"    "scale_fill_steps"      "scale_fill_steps2"    
[19] "scale_fill_stepsn"     "scale_fill_viridis_b"  "scale_fill_viridis_c" 
[22] "scale_fill_viridis_d"
```

If you want to set them manually use `scale_fill_manual`, with a vector of the colors inside, and them add to your ggplot code

### Example

#### Code

```
mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl,gear = as.factor(gear)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cyl,n,fill = gear))+
  geom_col(position = "fill")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red",'purple',"darkgoldenrod2"))
```

#### Output

[image]